# Javascript 3 way toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created 2 buttons, each for toggling a heading, the other for toggling paragraphs.

The problem is that for `Toggle Para` button, switching happens between 2 paragraphs on 2 clicks. 
On the third click, I want both paragraphs to be visible, and so on.

I need a help here.

```js
function toggle() {

  var x = document.getElementById("heading1");
  //var y = document.getElementById("p1");
  //var z = document.getElementById("p2");

  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function toggle1() {
  var y = document.getElementById("p1");
  var z = document.getElementById("p2");

  if (y.style.display == "block") {
    z.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else if (y.style.display == "none") {

    y.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading1">Toggling with Paragraphs</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="toggle.js"></script>
<p id="p1"> 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
  dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br>

<p id="p2"> 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
  dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br>

<input type="button" id="button1" value="Toggle H1" onclick="toggle()" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Toggle Para" onclick="toggle1()" />
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Just be aware that when (if?) you add a third paragraph the solution you've chosen gets much more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming you want to have three states:

1. p1 and p2 visible
2. p1 visible, p2 not
3. p2 visible, p1 not

The conditions for these states therefore depend on the current display state of both p1 and p2.
Then you can use the following script: (in which you can of course change the order of making paragraphs (in)visible.)

```js
function toggle()
{

    var x = document.getElementById("heading1");
    //var y = document.getElementById("p1");
    //var z = document.getElementById("p2");

    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function toggle1()
{
    var y = document.getElementById("p1");
    var z = document.getElementById("p2");
   if (y.style.display != "none" && z.style.display != "none") {
        z.style.display = "block";
         y.style.display = "none";
    } 
    else if (y.style.display == "none" && z.style.display != "none") {

        y.style.display ="block";
        z.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        y.style.display ="block";
        z.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
    <h1 id="heading1">Toggling with Paragraphs</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="toggle.js"></script>
    <p id="p1"> 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br>

    <p id="p2"> 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br>

    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Toggle H1" onclick="toggle()"/>
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="Toggle Para" onclick="toggle1()"/>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. This approach is good. Although, I was looking for a approach, where in we can avoid many if-else cases. What I initially thought was- Taking a counter variable, and using click value function, to  apply switch cases for the same. thanks..

Comment: @Kunal if thats what you wanted youve chosen the wrong solution. Check the other answer.

Comment: @Kunal that was not clear to me, therefore I followed your approach, but if you want that, you should indeed use the solution of Jamiec.

Comment: @rolfv1 Both are perfect ways. thnx!

Answer (score 1):

Store the possible (display) states of your paragraphs, and step through them as appropriate.

```js
function toggle()
{

    var x = document.getElementById("heading1");
    //var y = document.getElementById("p1");
    //var z = document.getElementById("p2");

    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

var states = [[true,true], [true,false],[false,true]];
var currentState = 0;
function toggle1()
{
    var y = document.getElementById("p1");
    var z = document.getElementById("p2");

    currentState++
    if(currentState>=states.length) currentState = 0;
    
    y.style.display = states[currentState][0] ? 'block' : 'none';
    z.style.display = states[currentState][1] ? 'block' : 'none';
   
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading1">Toggling with Paragraphs</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="toggle.js"></script>
    <p id="p1"> 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br>

    <p id="p2"> 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br>

    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Toggle H1" onclick="toggle()"/>
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="Toggle Para" onclick="toggle1()"/>
```

Comment: Elegant approach. You could of course also consider storing the `block` and `none` values in the `states` array, saves you two if statements.

Comment: @rolfv1 sure, but then it ties it to the `display` setting. When you decide you actually want it to control something else (eg visibility) a boolean is probably still fine.

Comment: @Jamiec perfect approach. Both approches are fair enough.